# Javascript - get pixel data from image under canvas element?

Tags: javascript, canvas

You can sample pixel color data on a canvas image with getImageData(). If I layer a transparent canvas element over a background image or flash movie, can I sample a color from that via the canvas tag?

Comment: This question is possibly relevant (and I'm trying to solve the same problem): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754865/how-to-get-the-rgb-value-of-an-image-in-a-page-using-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phil's right, you can't do it. Canvas, by design, only returns its own intrinsic pixel data, not any on-screen rendered content originating from other elements.

> You could make a canvas element that covers the entire page and captures an image of the rendered screen.

If possible, that would be a cross-site-scripting security hole. You could iframe a target site (leveraging the users cookies/authentication/intranet to access it), then suck out the content from it pixel by pixel.

Answer (score 2):

I think not. You would get the colour of the canvas at that point. I did find the method `document.defaultview.getComputedStyle(element,pseudoElt)`, but on a 1 pixel div with no background-color, it returned 'transparent'.

So, unfortunately, this may be impossible at present. What is your higher-level aim? We may be able to come up with an alternative route.

"I had an idea earlier to copy image data into a javascript object. You could make a canvas element that covers the entire page and captures an image of the rendered screen. Once you have that data, you could do real-world cross browser testing, perhaps."

If you don't mind that it's a static image, there is a great website that does this for you: [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/). It generates screenshots of your website running in a huge range of different browsers.

Comment: I had an idea earlier to copy image data into a javascript object. You could make a canvas element that covers the entire page and captures an image of the rendered screen. Once you have that data, you could do real-world cross browser testing, perhaps.

Comment: I've added a note to the answer about the browsershots website, which should do what you're thinking in a nice, simple fashion.