# how can i extend $.browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to write some jquery that will extend $.browser with some of my own properties. So it I can currently access $.browser.msie, how could I extend it to include $.browser.isPngSupported etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to check for PNG support with jQuery.Support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896014/is-it-possible-to-check-for-png-support-with-jquery-support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set `$.browser.isPngSupported` to `true` or `false`.

However, you should be extending [`$.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/), not `$.browser`.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing preference for $.support. Just to add a bit, [jQuery.com has this to say](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/): "We recommend against using [$.browser]; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery."

Answer (score 0):

```
var newData = {   'isPngSupported': true,
                  'more': 'x',
                  'evenMore':  'y' };

$.browser = $.extend( true, $.browser, newData );
```