# Replacing a png with a gif file if png is not supported in browser

Tags: html, png, gif

I know this issue deals with IE browsers failing to display PNG files, especially if you are a power user on Windows Vista and you are using IE7. My hope to find a solution to replace a PNG file with gif only if the png is not supported.  Is there a way from a javascript or css perspective to achieve such an effect?  I'm trying to accomplish this for background images on div tags.

Thanks!

Comment: PNGs are supported on IE7. Do you mean _transparent_ PNGs?

Comment: As a power user on vista you don't get either of them if you open up your browser in IE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use IE's [conditional css](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to override background images

```
<style type="text/css">
   div.something { background: url(someimage.png); }
</style>

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
   div.something { background: url(override.gif); }
</style>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `<!--` in the last line...unless it's there for other reasons/easy code-commenting?

Comment: Excellent work, and David is right about the tag.  This technique now leaves the hard work now up to the designer, to design the gif image in a way to match the png's transparency effect.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are some ideas over at this question:

[Is it possible to check for PNG support with jQuery.Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896014/is-it-possible-to-check-for-png-support-with-jquery-support)

you'll likely have to use some css hacks. to target IE 7.

this page has some tricks to do it:
http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/ie7-only-css-hacks/

Comment: None of the techniques mentioned on that 2nd link work for my version of IE7