# how to get the RGB value of an image in a page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to make a bookmark-let. But I'm stuck at a point.
I need to extract the RGB or the color value of an image of very x pixel using the "For Next" statement. But i don't know what function can help me to extract the RGB value. Can someone please help me out with the function that tells the value of RCG of a given point in a picture?

Comment: This questions appears to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think the links will help me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

This is a tough question.  There's no method I'm aware of in the standard DOM that would allow you to extract the RGB value of pixels in an `<img>`.

However, if you're willing to dig in to HTML5, you can take advantage of the [`<canvas>` element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#pixel-manipulation).  You can load an image into the canvas (`.drawImage()`) and then get the RGB values you're looking for (`.getImageData()`; see the link in SLaks’ answer).  Of course, this won't work on IE8 since it doesn't support `<canvas>`.

An alternative option might be to make an AJAX call to a web service to get pixel data.  The server-side script can load the image, get RGB values, and return it as JSON to your bookmarklet.  This obviously adds the latency of a roundtrip to a server, but is more compatible.  (Also consider cross-domain issues, however.)