# Convert an image to an RGB array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, rgb

Is it possible to get an array of pixels from a PNG or BMP image in Javascript? I'd like to obtain an RGB array from an image so that I can manipulate the array of pixels, and then draw the modified image on a canvas.

**UPDATE:** I found an exact duplicate here: [how to get the RGB value of an image in a page using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754865/how-to-get-the-rgb-value-of-an-image-in-a-page-using-javascript)

However, the answers don't go into much detail about how to actually solve this problem.

Comment: If you click on the link of the answer to that question it takes you to a detailed answer of how to invert the color of each pixel in an image. It should be trivial to convert that code into storing an array of pixels.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the RGB value of an image in a page using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754865/how-to-get-the-rgb-value-of-an-image-in-a-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a hundred tutorials on the net about using HTML Canvas [imageData](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-getimagedata), which gets the RGBA values of an canvas. Do a search for canvas imageData and you'll find plenty of info.

All you have to do is:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height).data;
```

imgData is now an array where every 4 places are each pixel. So `[0][1][2][3]` are the `[r][g][b][a]` of the first pixel.

Comment: What should the parameter type of "img" be? Should it be an image object, or should it be the image URL as a string?

Comment: @AndersonGreen an instance of Image object, you can get it via either DOM, make a new one by: `var img = new Image(); img.src = "http://..." or img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,...."`

Comment: I do not have <canvas/>, since I'm running a subset of XHTML, but I have <img/> How can I do that?

Comment: Would imgData be considered a byte array?

Comment: Just a note that I had to initialise the width and height for both the image and the canvas to make it work: `let image = new Image(800,600); [canvas.width, canvas.height] = [img.width, img.height];`