# Does JavaScript in the browser support BitmapData?

Tags: javascript, flash, bitmap, bitmapdata

Does JavaScript in the browser support a BitmapData like class? Here is a link to the documentation of the [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) class.

Comment: That's a Flash reference

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473484/convert-an-image-to-an-rgb-array-in-javascript) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could simulate it with the [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) interface.